# Reference to lookup column DataVerse with FIlter - PowerApps

Tags: powerapps, powerapps-formula, dataverse

Ok, let's contemplate the next scenario with powerapps:

We have a simple filter:

```
Filter(datasource, column1 = "condition")
```

After that you can refer a column like that:

```
Filter(datasource, column1 = "condition").Column2
```

But I realized that can't refer to a lookup column:

```
Filter(datasource, column1 = "condition").Column2.Value
```

So I can't do thigs like that:

```
Filter(datasource2, columnX in Filter(datasource1, column1="condition").Column2.Value
(column2 is a lookup column)
```

How could I filter a column using a "list" extracted from a filter with a lookup column? (as above)

Hope have explained well, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The way I have accomplished this is with AddColumns, but it's not delegable and could be an issue if datasource1 is large.  If so, then you can use a collection with the filter and then add the column to the collection.

> Filter(datasource2, columnX in AddColums(Filter(datasource1,
> column1="condition"), "New Column Name", Column2.Value).'New Column
> Name'

If you have a large datasource:

> Clearcollect(collectionName, Filter(datasource1,
> column1="condition"));
>
> Filter(datasource2, columnX in AddColums(collectionName, "New Column
> Name", Column2.Value).'New Column Name'

If there is a delegable way to do this, I would love to know.